# How to calculate regression coefficient and put it into each row of a table

Tags: sas

I have a SQL that would create for each customer a short excerpt of his history. Suppose the columns I am interested in are `TIMESTAMP` and `PURCHASE VALUE`. I'd like to calculate a linear regression for each customer and put this value into a table.

```
proc sql;
   create table CUSTOMERHISTORY as
   select 
       TIME_STAMP
      ,PURCHASE_VALUE
      ,CUSTOMER_ID
   from <my data source>
;quit;
```

The table is quite large; it would be best, if the table wouldn't have to loaded into RAM prior to computation.

I tried

```
proc reg
   data = CUSTOMERHISTORY;
   model PURCHASE_VALUE=TIME_STAMP;
   outest = OUTTABLE;
   by CUSTOMER_ID;
```

but it never wrote anything to the `OUTTABLE`. (I found parameter `outest` in http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect007.htm )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you link to, `outtest` is a parameter that you should give as a option to `proc reg`. So to get that specific output, your code should look as:

```
proc reg
   data = CUSTOMERHISTORY
   outest = OUTTABLE;
   model PURCHASE_VALUE=TIME_STAMP;
   by CUSTOMER_ID;
run;
```

Note that there is no semicolon between `data = ...` and `outtest = ...`.

Comment: You need to add a `RUN;` and/or a `QUIT;`  The model will not fit without one.

Comment: True, I ran it in EG and it fixes it automatically. I'll add that in.